# WPF TranslateTransform Error

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have a StackPanel that I am sliding left and right to simulate moving pages using TranslateTransform.

If I call the slide method once it works well. If I call my slide method twice in quick succession (in code), the second transform has the wrong start position and ends up in the wrong place.

How do I get my second translate to "refresh" its starting position?

Here is the StackPanel

```
    <StackPanel
        x:Name="MainPanel"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform
                x:Name="MainPanelTransform"
                />
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the slide code:

```
    private void SlidePage(int pagesToMove)
    {
        Storyboard sb = SlideEffect(MainPanel, (-PageWidth * pagesToMove));
        sb.Completed += SlideCompleted;
        sb.Begin();
    }

    private Storyboard SlideEffect(UIElement controlToAnimate, double positionToMove)
    {
        //Get position of stackpanel
        var gt = controlToAnimate.TransformToVisual(MainGrid);
        var p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        //add new storyboard and animation
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        var da = new DoubleAnimation { To = p.X + positionToMove };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(da, controlToAnimate);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
        //Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].X"));

        var ee = new ExponentialEase { Exponent = 6.0, EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
        da.EasingFunction = ee;

        sb.Children.Add(da);
        return sb;

    }
```

The offending line of code is this:

```
var p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

The second time I call the SlideEffect method it has the same value as the first time. It seems like the animations are getting buffered and run together. Is there any way to stop the buffering?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change a [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) property of `Storyboard`?

**UPDATE:**

I have a [bug in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874885/visual-studio-process-unable-to-copy-file), so I couldn't reproduce your situation. But I may recommend you:

1. Try to disable the `EasingFunction`. Maybe `Storyboard.Completed` fires before the `Storyboard` actually completed;
2. Are you sure, that transform changes actual coordinates? I think it is the solution, but not sure.
3. In the `Storyboard.Completed` you could manually update transform coordinates:

   ```
   MainPanelTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, null);
   MainPanelTransform.X = -100;
   ```

Comment: Good idea. Tried both Stop and HoldEnd and same problem. I believe that the problem is due to the async nature of the animations. The second is starting before the first has updated the value.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the async nature of animations. The second animation runs before the first has finished or even called Completed. I changed the code to use TranslateTransform directly without using a storyboard and all works well.